Set Anchor in Hyperlink to Range Address Offset
I have a macro that performs the following process:

"Company Name" is entered into cell C2 of sheet 'Company List'.
Macro button is pressed in 'Company List'.
The "Company Name" is then copied and inserted alphabetically into Column B of 'Company List' sheet.
Worksheet 'Company Name' is created from a template using the "Company Name".

Hyperlink to sheet 'Company Name' needs to be created in column C on 'Company List' sheet using Hyperlinks.Add.  I believe I have to find the address of the inserted "Company Name" in 'Company List', then Offset that address to Column C, then use the adjusted address to create the hyperlink.  My attempted code is as follows :
Sub Button1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim companyList As Worksheet
    Dim companyName As Range
    Dim companies As Range
    Dim lPosition As Long
    Dim companyNameAddress As Range
    Dim companyOverview As Range
    
    Set companyList = ActiveSheet
    Set companies = companyList.Range("B5:B" & Rows.Count)
    Set companyName = companyList.Range("C2")
        If Not IsEmpty(companyName.Value) Then
            lPosition = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CStr(companyName.Text), companies, 1)
            companies(lPosition + 1).Insert
            companies(lPosition + 1).Value = CStr(companyName.Text)
            '*** CREATE NEW COMPANY SHEET ***
                '--- Do Stuff ---
                
            '*** FIND CELL ADDRESS OF NEW COMPANY IN COMPANIES ***
            Set companyNameAddress = companyList.Range("B5:B" & Rows.Count).Find(CStr(companyName.Text), lookat:=xlPart)
            Set companyOverview = companyNameAddress.Offset(0, 1)
                
            '*** INSERT HYPERLINKS FOR COMPANY SHEETS ***
            With companyList
                Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(companyOverview), _
                               Address:="", _
                               SubAddress:=" '" & CStr(companyName.Text) & "'!B2", _
                               TextToDisplay:="Overview"
            

            End With
            companyList.Range("C2").ClearContents
        
        Else
            MsgBox "Enter Company Name"
        End If
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

This throws a 1004 error: Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed.  How do I go about finding the location for where the hyperlink needs to go, then insert that cell (range) into the Anchor of the Hyperlinks.Add function?  I'm assuming that's the issue here.

Is this just Anchor:=companyOverview?

Which line? Click Debug button on popup error window, VBE will highlight the code line which throws the error.


Using .Range(companyOverview) attempts to find a range named as the value of cell (companyOverview). eg. if the conent of companyOverview is mydata, then .Range(companyOverview) refers to the named range Range("mydata").
If the named range specified by companyOverview doesn't exist, it will result in a runtime error 1004.

 ' Code from OP
 With companyList
     Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(companyOverview), _



Actually, you can use it as Anchor:=companyOverview.
The Text property of a Range object returns the content as a String, regardless of the content type in the cell. Therefore, there's no need for an additional CStr() conversion.

    With companyList
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=companyOverview, _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & companyName.Text & "'!B2", _
            TextToDisplay:="Overview"
    End With

